# WSO2 API Manager (1.10.0) LDAP Roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a LDAP Second store at APIM (1.10.0).
When I create one aplication, two roles is created like this:

```
- Application/<user>_<Name application>_PRODUCTION
- Application/<user>_<Name application>_SANDBOX
```

I' d like create it at LDAP automaticaly . How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by create in LDAP automatically?

Comment: I want that APIM creates this roles at LDAP

Answer (score 1):

By design this role is created under Application which is an internal role. One of the benefits of creating under application is that this role can be assigned to a user of any domain(primary/secondary) where as if the role was created under a specific domain then the role would not be available for other domain users

regards,shavantha